# Ionic Transition Glitch in iOS 9

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm encountering some transition glitch w/ my App, it only appears in iOS 9 and the app is compiled through Phonegap build.

Here's a sample video showing the transition glitch. [link](https://youtu.be/SmWLRNtrF3g)

I don't know if this would help but here's my gist for the config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="au.gov.nal.hearing.myhearing" version="0.7.9" versionCode="607" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

  <gap:platform name="ios"/>
  <gap:platform name="android"/>

  <name>My Hearing</name>

  <description>My Hearing App</description>

  <author email="rene@bywave.com.au" href="http://bywave.com.au/">Renemari Padillo</author>

  <content src="index.html"/>

  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1.0"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="handset" />

  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification" />
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

  <!-- Whitelist URLs -->
  <access origin="*" />
  <access origin="*.google.com" />
  <access origin="*.parse.com" />
  <access origin="*.googleapis.com" />
  <access origin="*.gstatic.com" />
  <access origin="*.googleusercontent.com" />
  <access origin="google.com" subdomains="true"/>
  <access origin="googleapis.com" subdomains="true"/>
  <access origin="gstatic.com" subdomains="true"/>
  <access origin="googleusercontent.com" subdomains="true"/>
  <access origin="parse.com" subdomains="true"/>

  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />
  <allow-intent href="*" launch-external="yes" />

  <feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
  </feature>
  <feature name="debug-server" required="true">
    <param name="domain" value="http://192.168.15.130:8080"/>
    <param name="key" value="key1"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser"/>
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
  </feature>

  <gap:plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" version="1.0.3"/>
  <gap:plugin name="uk.co.whiteoctober.cordova.appversion" version="0.1.4"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4"/>
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation" version="0.3.10"/>
  <gap:plugin name="com.medlei.pushplugin" version="0.1.2">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="Bd8dbfMRwToBaB8UP0SWZ0ZlgYJ2o1CqMtFqzkuh"/>
    <param name="CLIENT_KEY" value="0ev2Je3JX3ln5XJHTsFTbJwNpG7k5eXpt5l83CVs"/>
  </gap:plugin>

  <icon src="resources/icon.png" />
  <gap:splash src="resources/splash.png" />

  <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" gap:density="ldpi"/>
  <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" gap:density="mdpi"/>
  <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" gap:density="hdpi"/>
  <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" gap:density="xhdpi"/>
  <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" gap:density="xxhdpi"/>
  <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" gap:density="xxxhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-xxhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-xxxhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-xxhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-xxxhdpi"/>

  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
  <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" height="1136" width="640"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h@2x.png" height="1334" width="750"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" height="2208" width="1242"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" height="1242" width="2208"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" height="1536" width="2048"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" height="768" width="1024"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" height="2048" width="1536"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" height="1024" width="768"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" height="960" width="640"/>
  <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" height="480" width="320"/>

</widget>
```

I've found some related articles, but it doesn't sovle my problem.

iOS version - 9.0.1

Does anyone also encountered this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a temporary patch fix for this issue:
https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c

````
/**
 * ==================  angular-ios9-uiwebview.patch.js v1.1.1 ==================
 *
 * This patch works around iOS9 UIWebView regression that causes infinite digest
 * errors in Angular.
 *
 * The patch can be applied to Angular 1.2.0 – 1.4.5. Newer versions of Angular
 * have the workaround baked in.
 *
 * To apply this patch load/bundle this file with your application and add a
 * dependency on the "ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch" module to your main app module.
 *
 * For example:
 *
 * ```
 * angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])`
 * ```
 *
 * becomes
 *
 * ```
 * angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch'])
 * ```
 *
 *
 * More info:
 * - https://openradar.appspot.com/22186109
 * - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12241
 * - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4082
 *
 *
 * @license AngularJS
 * (c) 2010-2015 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */

angular.module('ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch', ['ng']).config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  'use strict';

  $provide.decorator('$browser', ['$delegate', '$window', function($delegate, $window) {

    if (isIOS9UIWebView($window.navigator.userAgent)) {
      return applyIOS9Shim($delegate);
    }

    return $delegate;

    function isIOS9UIWebView(userAgent) {
      return /(iPhone|iPad|iPod).* OS 9_\d/.test(userAgent) && !/Version\/9\./.test(userAgent);
    }

    function applyIOS9Shim(browser) {
      var pendingLocationUrl = null;
      var originalUrlFn= browser.url;

      browser.url = function() {
        if (arguments.length) {
          pendingLocationUrl = arguments[0];
          return originalUrlFn.apply(browser, arguments);
        }

        return pendingLocationUrl || originalUrlFn.apply(browser, arguments);
      };

      window.addEventListener('popstate', clearPendingLocationUrl, false);
      window.addEventListener('hashchange', clearPendingLocationUrl, false);

      function clearPendingLocationUrl() {
        pendingLocationUrl = null;
      }

      return browser;
    }
  }]);
}]);
````

Answer (score 0):

In the version of 1.1.1 this bug is fixed:

Check out [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and related commit: [#e5b85df](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/e5b85df) on Github.